# admin-ajax.php call returns 404 error as soon as an object with value 'varchar' is being passed

Tags: ajax, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have the following issue with wordpress ajax call.
Whenever I send a parameter that contains the string "varchar" it results in 404 Not Found error.
When I would change it to for instance "varchar1" it returns 200 Success

The following ajax call returns 404:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'send_email',
        data: 'varchar'
    },
```

But this ajax call returns 200:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'send_email',
        data: 'varchar1'
    },
```

I also tried to change the parameter key "data" to something else, this does not make any difference.
I use both the actions for the ajax call: `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_`

Because I can't think of anything else, my question is: **Could this be a server setting of some sort?**

Comment: Would you please share also your php function for this ajax call.

Comment: it's simply this: `public static function send_email( $settings=null ) { echo 'test'; die(); }`